# What's the meaning of `EIO` and `t` in socketio

Tags: socket.io

I use python-socketio create a project.

Bellow is a request:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2018 05:41:17] "GET /socket.io/?
EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M6y1xWT&sid=446d37ddf93f471888abf02017a5a576 HTTP/1.1" 
200 269 0.000470
```

I want to know the params meaning.

Now I know `transport` (transport type), `sid` (session id), but I don't know the `EIO` and `t` there.

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-protocol/issues/27

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 9):

The `EIO` stands for the Engine.IO version which happens to be `3` in your case
and `t` stands for the hashed timestamp for caching purposes.